# Azure SQL -- what is vCore actually

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

We are planning to create and Azure SQL Managed Instance. When we select Vcore based purchasing model, how is the CPU Physical Cores calculated.

As per Microsoft docs:
Gen5 logical CPUs are based on Intel® E5-2673 v4 (Broadwell) 2.3 GHz, Intel® SP-8160 (Skylake), and Intel® 8272CL (Cascade Lake) 2.5 GHz processors, fast NVMe SSD, hyper-threaded logical core, and compute sizes between 4 and 80 cores.

So, if we select 8 vCore then

1. how is the CPU allocated to me(Intel® E5-2673 v4/Intel® SP-8160/Intel® 8272CL)
2. Can I choose my own CPU
3. If I say, since the CPU is either 18/24/26 Core, so 8 vCore = 8*16/8*24/8*26. Will that be a correct understanding

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Managed Instance combines the SQL Server database engine with all the benefits of a fully managed platform as a service.

Microsoft Azure uses predefined hardware(Intel® E5-2673 v4/Intel® SP-8160/Intel® 8272CL) for Azure SQL Managed Instance. Microsoft Azure are responsible for the hardware and fully operates allocation of resources and hardware for Azure SQL Managed Instance.

You cannot choose exact hardware, CPU, Memory or Storage type instead you can select only high level options like Service Tier, Hardware Generation, amount of vCores and Storage in GB.

[image]

Intel® E5-2673 v4 has 20 Cores

Intel® SP-8160 v4 has 24 Cores

Intel® 8272CL has 26 Cores

vCore is short for virtual core and it's a model that was designed to make it simpler to translate your on prem hardware resource specs into similar specs on the Azure SQL database platform

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/service-tiers-managed-instance-vcore?tabs=azure-portal